# Как проверить наличие ссылки в строке на php

Tags: php

Как проверить наличие ссылки в строке на php

Comment: `strpos($html, 'http://')` м?

Comment: `vkontakte.com`

Comment: Если нужно текст превращать в ссылку по принципу вк, там скорее всего регулярка, находит точку и разделяет пробелами текст. ` vkontakte.com `

Answer (score 6):

Пользуйтесь регулярными выражениями  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

Попробуйте этот шаблон

```
 /^(?:http:\/\/)?[-0-9a-z._]*.\w{2,4}[:0-9]*$/

$subject = "abc http://googl.com xyz";
$pattern = '/^(?:http:\/\/)?[-0-9a-z._]*.\w{2,4}[:0-9]*$/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
```

Ну или  **strpos()** http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php

```
$mystring = 'abc http://googl.com xyz';
$findme   = 'http://';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$mystring'";
    echo " в позиции $pos";
}
```

Смотря какие условия вас устраивают.

Comment: `vkontakte.ru/wefgwegfweg`  не хочет брать

Comment: @ikerya, это берёт `$html = preg_replace('@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([-\w]+\.)+([^\s]+)+[^,.\s])@', '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank">$1$2$3$4</a>', $html);`

Comment: мои премьеры находят строки с наличием http:// в ссылках,

Comment: нужно без http .

Comment: @Doofy Ссылки так http$2://$4 не выглядят . Тут дело в том что нету универсального решения для ваших нужд.Ргулярные выражния вам в помощь ,изучайте.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, у меня нет никаких нужд, мне всё равно. А пример что я скинул в комменте работает и с http и без

Comment: Ааа понял ,ну удачи вам :)

Comment: Просто тут есть опасность ,строки на подобие vkontakte.ru равны (abc.Но , abc.Или).То Бишь строка заканчивается ,точка ,и начинается с 2 или 3 букв .Пример строки    "прошу вас господа сесть.Ну а ты встань". Получается 'сесть.Ну' это ссылка ?

Comment: Я думаю эту проблему можно решить только если послать запрос по этой ссылкe и проверить заголовки ,curl_getinfo()  esli http_code > 0 то это точно ссылка , ну или что то в этом вроде

Answer (score 2):

Так всё просто лучше и безопаснее превращать разрешённые ссылки в ссылке кода к примеру

```
// массив разрешённых доменов
$linksDomain = array(
  'vk.com',
  'ok.ru'
);

// замена разрешённого доменна на ссылку
function replaceDomain(&$text,$domain) {
     // вычислим офсет строки
     $offset = strpos($domain,$text);
     // так как во многих случаяд домен оканчиваеться на символ пробела 
     // возьмём длину до него
     $to = strpos(" ",$text,$offset);
     // получим найденную строку
     $stringYes = substr($text,$offset,$to);
     // заменяем её в исходной строке на ссылку
     $text = str_replace($stringYes,"<a href='$stringYes'>$stringYes</a>",$text); 
}

// далее ищем в тексте совпадения если они есть то возьмём кусок этого url
foreach($linksDomain as $_domain) {
  if(strpos($text,'https://'.$domain) !== false) { // если есть что то подобное в тексте получаем оффсет
     replaceDomain($text,'https://'.$_domain);
  } elseif(strpos($text,'http://'.$_domain) !== false) {
     replaceDomain($text,'https://'.$_domain);
  } elseif(strpos($text,$_domain)) {
     replaceDomain($text,$_domain);
  }
}
```

предвкушая минусы, поставьте палец вверх, хочу 1000 репутации :D шутка конечно, а способ велосипед на тему регулярки, хотя может быть полезен.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match("/^(http://|https://)((www.|([w, -]+.))?([w, -]+.)(com|net|org|info|biz|spb.ru|msk.ru|com.ru|org.  ru|net.ru|ru|su|us|bz|kz|ws|рф|pro))(|/.*)$/u", $my_str)) { 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]